# Counting rows from each day from last 60 days

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I would like to count rows from each day from last 60 days and return this as list.

**models.py**

```
class Error(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    adding_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

In database I have:

```
   name    | adding_time
   ------------------------------------
   error_1 | 2017-04-10 10:47:33.204518
   error_2 | 2017-04-10 11:01:12.339936
   error_3 | 2017-04-21 08:40:56.862731
   error_4 | 2017-04-21 08:45:50.235212
```

What I would like to achieve is list of dates and counted rows in that day:

```
[{'count': 2, 'adding_date': '2017-04-10'}, {'count': 2, 'adding_date': '2017-04-21'}]
```

So far, I have done someting like this:

```
last_30_days_errors = Error.filter(adding_time__lte=datetime.datetime.today(),adding_time__gt=datetime.datetime.today()-datetime.timedelta(days=60))

errors_dates = last_30_days_errors.extra({'adding_date': 'date(adding_time)'}).values('adding_date')
```

It is returning:

```
>>> [{'count': 1, 'adding_date': '2017-04-10'}, {'count': 1, 'adding_date': '2017-04-10'}, {'count': 1, 'adding_date': '2017-04-21'}, {'count': 1, 'adding_date': '2017-04-21'}]
```

I can parse it, but is there any method to do it by a query? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
from django.db.models import Count
last_30_days_errors.extra({'adding_time':"date(adding_time)"}).values('adding_time').annotate(count=Count('id'))
```

Comment: Working! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
import pytz
from django.db.models import Count
from django.db.models.expressions import DateTime
annotate_list = [Count('id')]
group_by_list = ["interval"]
last_30_days_errors.annotate(interval=DateTime('adding_time', "days",pytz.timezone("UTC"))).values(*group_by_list).annotate(*annotate_list)
```

Comment: The .extra used in the above answer should not be used. Check here==> https://imgur.com/Qn4SQD5